# Threading Declaration Issues

Tags: c#

I'm using this code

```
Thread T = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Listen));
T.IsBackground = true;
T.Start();
```

And its returning these errors;

[Line 2] Invalid token '=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
[Line 3] Invalid token '(' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

Can someone shed some light on whats going wrong here because I don't really know what is.

Comment: Is this in Visual Studio? If so, hover your mouse over **Thread** and report back what namespace is displayed in the popup hint.

Comment: Put your code into a method - you can't just put it right in the class declaration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're writing those 3 lines inside a class, and not inside a method of that class.

This will produce that error:

```
public class Dummy
{
    Thread T = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Listen));
    T.IsBackground = true;
    T.Start();

    ...
}
```

This will not:

```
public class Dummy
{
    public void Test()
    {
        Thread T = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Listen));
        T.IsBackground = true;
        T.Start();
    }

    ...
}
```